# A convenient logging statement for C++ using boost::format

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, boost-format

I want to design a logging function with the following characteristics:

- based on std::string rather than char*
- supports variable number of variables, like printf
- accepts as first parameter a severity level
- avoids formatting overhead when severity level is below logging level
- as simple as printf, or nearly so

I'm inclined to use boost::format because of its automatic type conversion.  But here are some problems I see:

Its syntax is a little awkward: `format("Mgr %s on pid %d is in state %s" % mgr % pid % s)` is a little hard on the eyes (the list nature of the variables isn't as evident without commas). A log invocation would look like this:

```
mylog(INFO, format("Mgr %s on pid %d is in state %s" % mgr % pid % s));
```

What's worse, is it even possible to implement mylog() to check if we're logging INFO messages *before* the format object is constructed?

The other approach I thought about, which looks closer to printf, would be

```
mylog(INFO, "Mgr %s on pid %d is in state %s", mgr, pid, s);
```

or even

```
mylog_info("Mgr %s on pid %d is in state %s", mgr, pid, s);
```

The implementation would be something like:

```
mylog(int severity, string pattern, ...) {
    if (severity >= LOGLEVEL) {
        boost::format fmt(pattern);
        for parm /* remaining parameters */ {
            fmt % parm; // feed into format one at a time
        }
    }
}
```

This certainly defers construction of the **format** object until it's needed.  But from what I can tell, there's no way, when traversing a variable argument list, to tell when you've reached the end!

Can someone suggest a syntactically simple technique of accomplishing this?

**Note: I have g++ 4.4, which does not support all of c++11 (although it does support variadic templates)**

Comment: You could implement the log as a stream, and write to it just like you might write to std::cout. E.G.: `log << LEVEL_INFO << "Mgr " << s << " on pid " << pid << " is in state " << s << "\n"` Just thinking out loud...

Comment: Please note that [g++4.4 **does** support variadic templates](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variadic templates and recursion.

> **Note:** Since you mention GCC 4.4, [this feature is available](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) for that compiler, but it is not enabled by default. You have to add either the `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` option to the compiler to enable the feature.

A solution could be implemented as something along these lines:

```
// Does the actual logging of the formatted message
void mylog_r (int severity, boost::format &fmt) {
  std::cout << "[" << severity << "] "
            << fmt
            << std::endl;
}

// Unpacks the variadic arguments one at a time recursively
template <typename T, typename... Params>
void mylog_r (int severity, boost::format &fmt, T arg, Params... parameters) {
  mylog_r(severity, fmt % arg, parameters...); // recursively unpack
}

// This version of mylog() checks severity and converts fmt to boost::format
template <typename... Params>
void mylog (int severity, std::string fmt, Params... parameters) {
  if (severity < LEVEL) return;
  boost::format bfmt(fmt);
  mylog_r(severity, bfmt, parameters...);
}
```

Comment: This is going to take a bit of studying to understand what's going on.  I looked at the code you linked to, but so far I'm unclear about how it works with format() and args.

Comment: @Chap: This is just the syntax to use variadic templates. The template functions unpack the variadic arguments one at a time, and recursively calls itself until there are no more arguments, at which point it calls the non-template version.

Comment: @Chap: IDEONE doesn't have Boost, so I had to fabricate something simple to just illustrate the unpacking of the variadic arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  Unfortunately, it appears that variadic templates are new with c++11, which is not yet available where I work.  Will amend my question to note that.

Comment: Okay - this works on the Apple clang-425 compiler (and I imagine it also will at work, using g++ 4.4 and the appropriate flags).  Is it absolutely necessary that there be a separate version of mylog() for when the number of parameters is zero?  (i.e. "when there is no formatting to be done")  I don't understand everything that's going on yet, but I wondered if there might be a unified solution for "zero or more parameters"?

Comment: The recursive template expansion is actually occurring inline, and when the compiler unpacks down to the point of no more parameters, you would get a compilation error unless it had a different function to call at that point. So you need the extra `mylog_r()`, but you might not need the extra `mylog()`. Let me work on that.

Comment: Right - we need a separate case for the terminal condition, but can we also use that for the degenerate case?  If I'm using the terminology correctly...

Comment: @Chap: Okay, I simplified it a bit. See if that is more intuitive.

Comment: A lot!  Note - on my compilers, I had to remove `typename T,` from the third function (mylog) for it to compile.  But now it's great - exactly what I need.

Comment: @Chap: Doh! I didn't paste in the simplified code, but edited it down to what I thought was the same as what I tested with. Fixed. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, i.e., like an implementation of printf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum Info_t
  {
    NONE,
    WARNING,
    ERROR   // so on
  };

int myLog(Info_t severity, string format, ...)
{
  int done = 0;
  if ( severity > WARNING ) {
    va_list arg;

    va_start(arg, format.c_str());
    done = vfprintf(stdout, format.c_str(), arg);
    va_end(arg);
  }

  return done;
}

int main()
{
  myLog(NONE, "Print %s %d.\n", "NONE", 0);
  myLog(WARNING, "Print %s %d.\n", "WARNING", 1);
  myLog(ERROR, "Print %s %d.\n", "ERROR", 2);
}
```